# Different behavior depending on the size of a buffer

Tags: c#, .net, clr

I have a simple **value type** that wraps **a buffer allocated on the stack**:

```
unsafe struct Value
{
    // public fixed byte Data[1073741800]; // StackOverflow (2^30 - 24)
    // public fixed byte Data[1073741801]; // InvalidProgram
    // public fixed byte Data[2147483631]; // InvalidProgram
    // public fixed byte Data[2147483632]; //OutOfMemory (2^31 - 16)
    public fixed byte Data[2147483647]; // OutOfMemory
}
```

used this way:

```
unsafe static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Value value;
    value.Data[0] = 0;
}
```

If the buffer is too big then stack-overflows can happen, and this is expected.

But depending on the size of the buffer the behavior of the CLR varies :

- for sizes **up to 1073741800 (2^30 - 24)** it throws a **StackOverflowException**
- for sizes **in the range [1073741801, 2147483631]** it throws an **InvalidProgramException**
- for sizes **in the range [2147483632 (2^31 - 16), 2147483647]** it throws an **OutOfMemoryException**

If it matters it's a release x86 build.

It's consistent across runtimes : same behavior with .Net 2.0 and .Net 4.5, so it seems like it's not a bug.

**Why this varying behavior?**

**Is it documented somewhere?**

Thanks for any pointer.

---

**EDIT**

I've tested with **Mono 3.2.3** and the behavior is similar, i.e. there is three levels of error : SO -> IP -> OOM, but the thresholds are not the same.

I don't know how the Mono team develops its implementation nowadays, if it is completely independent of if it "copy-paste" from the MS implementation.

In the first case it means this behavior must be specified somewhere because two different teams working independently producing the same strange behavior is too big a coincidence, so they must follow the same specifications.

In the second case they could have simply imported a glitch in the MS implementation...

Would be fine to have some feedback from any of the team.

If there is no feedback here I'll post some tickets to MS and Mono.

Comment: Hard to believe this matters.  IPE is probably from the verifier, OOM is probably from an overflow.  Call Microsoft Support if this really matters.

Comment: @HansPassant: thanks for the clues. No need to call, there is nothing critical :) just found this while playing with .Net. Just curious about the rationales if any.

Answer (score 0):

***Speculation***:

I believe it has to do with which step in the process failed.

The first step is to allocate the object.  A 32-bit .NET application cannot reference more than 2^31 bytes of memory, ***I believe***, and the rest of your application is using the other 16 bytes.  My guess as to why you don't get a stack overflow exception here is because it isn't actually allocating the memory yet, it is just checking to see if it could possibly allocate the memory.  Alternatively, depending on how the CLR implements stack vs heap, it may be that the stack is a virtual concept and the allocation is actually done at this step then later the virtual stack will point to it.

The next step is to attempt to JIT compile the constructor of your type I, ***believe***.  At this time, JIT Compilation will fail because for whatever reason it can't reference array elements larger than 2^30 - 24 as to why it can't, I am not sure.  I couldn't find anything about it in ECMA-355.  I am not sure if this is a compiler bug or a CLR bug.  Assuming the spec doesn't specify array size limits then I would call this a CLR bug.  If it does, then it is a compiler bug for generating code that can't be JIT compiled.

Finally it tries to put the thing on the stack and that fails, as you expected, since the object is likely substantially larger than your stack size.  As mentioned in step one, perhaps internally the CLR stack is a virtual concept rather than a physical block of memory of stack-size.  If that is the case then all that is happening here is a pointer is created to the object you allocated on the heap and the stack size is updated with `+= size_of_thing_being_referenced`.  Alternatively, if the stack is an actual chunk of memory in the CLR then at this step stack allocation is attempted and fails.

ECMA-355 §III.1 speaks briefly about how stack management is an implementation detail which means the CLR does magic to make it work and you have found a way to glimpse into that magic.

Comment: Thanks for looking at the issue. :) I don't agree on two points: 1) I guess all the CLR plumbing + my small program consumes far more than 16 bytes of memory so the 16 magic number may have another explanation 2) AFAIK under the hood the CLR uses native threads with "native" stack so I don't think there is any kind of virtualization, tough it's true another CLI implementation could do this. You must be right when you say it could fail due to an anticipated check for available memory, probably done by the verifier like Hans mentioned.